# War, spring and tomcat 7

Tags: spring, tomcat, gradle, war

I want to create a REST Web Service with Spring Framework on an Apache tomcat 7 server.

So, I took the build.gradle from the tutorial, I created my Ws and create main controller (/greeting) and my Application.class with the main method.

Then, I gradle clean build my solution and I get a war.

I deploy this war with the manager ui of tomcat server, and when I try to request the url localhost:8080/mySoft/greeting, I got a 404 error.

Can anybody help me ?

Cordially

---

I followed the tutorial, but I deploy the app like a war. So it should be on localhost:8080/myApp/greeting. localhost:8080/greeting deosnt work...

```
    Application.java



        package main.java;

    import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;

    @Configuration
    @EnableWebMvc
    public class Application {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        }

    }
```

```
    HelloController.java



    package com.id2tel.controller;

    import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;

    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

    @Controller
    public class HomeController {

        private static final String template = "Hello, %s!";
        private final AtomicLong counter = new AtomicLong();

        @RequestMapping("/greeting")
        public @ResponseBody
        Greeting greeting(
                @RequestParam(value = "name", required = false, defaultValue = "World") String name) {
            return new Greeting(counter.incrementAndGet(), String.format(template,
                    name));
        }
    }
```

And the basic greeting class provided by spring.

---

I created the HelloWebXml class.

I checked my catalina logs and I find this :

```
Infos: Déploiement de l'archive D:\j2ee\apache-tomcat-7.0.52-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-7.0.52\webapps\gs-convert-jar-to-war-0.1.0.war de l'application web
mars 24, 2014 8:28:57 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase addChildInternal
Grave: ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/gs-convert-jar-to-war-0.1.0]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1073)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:553)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1648)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1445)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.upload(HTMLManagerServlet.java:284)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:206)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:213)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2441)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:2430)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Comment: anything on the log or console? Check catalina.out on tomcat/log

Comment: If you are folowing the tutorial then you will get the JSON here .. localhost:8080/greeting

Comment: Please post your code as well . It will help to solve the problem

Answer (score 1):

If you are following the tutorial, [Here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/)
 Your url for the service should be

```
http://localhost:8080/greeting
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see - basing on your `Application` class, did not convert your application to WAR.

If you deploy Spring Boot based application to application server, remember to convert it to WAR in a way described in guide: https://spring.io/guides/gs/convert-jar-to-war/

Comment: I did this. And I obtain a war file, not a jar file

Comment: Alright, and did you also created class ```HelloWebXml``` like it's explained in tutorial?